# Changing page values based on a button press

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

What I'm trying to make happen

- User clicks `babyOneButton`
- babyOneButton sets the profile_selected attribute in the `GENERAL_PREFERENCES.xml` shared preferences file
- `babyOneButton` checks if the XML file exists
- (1) If it does, send the user the to the page to edit the profile
- (2) If it doesn't, send the user to the page to create a new profile
- On either page, 'BABY_ONE_PROFILE.xml' data would be shown.

What it's actually doing:

- User clicks `babyOneButton`
- Sometimes after pressing submit on `NewChildProfile`, the name will show up on `MainActivity` where baby2's name should be?
- No matter if the XML file exists or not, the user is always sent to the page to make a new profile. (If I switch the if/else statements around they'll always be sent to the manage page, so I'm assuming my way of finding if the profile exists isn't correct).
- `BABY_TWO_PROFILE` is always the data shown on `NewBabyProfile`.

**MainActivity.java**
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
SharedPreferences generalPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor generalPrefsEditor; 
public static String profileSelected;
public static String babyOneName;
public static String babyTwoName;
File file1, file2, file3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    file1 = new File("/data/data/com.parentingreminders/shared_prefs/BABY_ONE_PROFILE.XML");
    file2 = new File("/data/data/com.parentingreminders/shared_prefs/BABY_TWO_PROFILE.XML");

    String BABY_ONE_PROFILE = getString(R.string.baby_one_profile);
    String BABY_TWO_PROFILE = getString(R.string.baby_two_profile);

    SharedPreferences babyOneProfile = getSharedPreferences(BABY_ONE_PROFILE, 0);
    SharedPreferences babyTwoProfile = getSharedPreferences(BABY_TWO_PROFILE, 0);

    String babyOneName = babyOneProfile.getString("name", "name");
    TextView babyOneNameOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baby_1_name);
    babyOneNameOutput.setText(babyOneName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + babyOneName.substring(1));

    String babyTwoName = babyTwoProfile.getString("name", "name");
    TextView babyTwoNameOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baby_2_name);
    babyTwoNameOutput.setText(babyTwoName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + babyTwoName.substring(1));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_baby_profile, menu);
    return true;
}

public void babyOneButtonClick(View view) {

    profileSelected = "1";
    generalPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.general_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    generalPrefsEditor = generalPrefs.edit();
    generalPrefsEditor.putString("profile_selected", profileSelected).commit();

    if (file1.exists()) {
        Intent goToManageBaby1 = new Intent(this, ManageBaby1.class);
        startActivity(goToManageBaby1);
    } else {
        Intent goToNewBabyProfile = new Intent(this, NewBabyProfile.class);
        startActivity(goToNewBabyProfile);
    }
```

}

```
public void babyTwoButtonClick(View view) {

    profileSelected = "2";
    generalPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.general_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    generalPrefsEditor = generalPrefs.edit();
    generalPrefsEditor.putString("profile_selected", profileSelected).commit();


    if (file2.exists()) {
        Intent goToManageBaby1 = new Intent(this, ManageBaby1.class);
        startActivity(goToManageBaby1);
    } else {
        Intent goToNewBabyProfile = new Intent(this, NewBabyProfile.class);
        startActivity(goToNewBabyProfile);
    }
```

}}

**NewBabyProfile.java**
    public class NewBabyProfile extends Activity {

```
public static String gender = "na";
public static String name = "na";
public static String dobMonth = "January";
public static String dobDay = "01";
public static String dobYear = "1900";
public static String feedingOz = "00";
public static String feedingHrs = "00";
public static String awakeHrs = "00";
public static int activeStartHour = 0;
public static int activeStartMinute = 0;
public static int activeEnd = 0;
public static String allDay = "no";
public static Spinner mSpinner;
public static int profileNumber;
public static String profileCreated;
public static String profileSelected;

SharedPreferences babyProfile, generalPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor, generalPrefsEditor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_baby_profile);

    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dob_month);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.months_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    generalPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.general_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    generalPrefsEditor = generalPrefs.edit();


    // SharedPreferences initializations
    profileSelected = generalPrefs.getString("profile_selected", "profileSelected");

    if (profileSelected == "1") {
        babyProfile = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), 0);
    } 

    if (profileSelected == "2"){
        babyProfile = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_two_profile), 0);
    }

    editor = babyProfile.edit();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_baby_profile, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View genderSelection){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) genderSelection).isChecked();

    switch(genderSelection.getId()) {
        case R.id.gender_boy:
            if (checked)
                gender = "boy";
            break;

        case R.id.gender_girl:
            if (checked)
                gender = "girl";
            break;
    }


}



public void submitNewBabyProfile(View view) {

    // Submit name
    EditText nameInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_input);
    name = nameInput.getText().toString().trim();
    editor.putString("name",name).commit();

    // Submit gender 
    editor.putString("gender",gender).commit();

    // Submit date of birth
    String dobMonth = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    editor.putString("dob_month",dobMonth).commit();

    EditText dobDayInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob_day);
    dobDay = dobDayInput.getText().toString().trim();
    editor.putString("dob_day",dobDay).commit();

    EditText dobYearInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob_year);
    dobYear = dobYearInput.getText().toString().trim();
    editor.putString("dob_year",dobYear).commit();

    // Submit feeding information
    EditText feedingOzInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feeding_oz_input);
    feedingOz = feedingOzInput.getText().toString().trim();
    editor.putString("feeding_oz_input",feedingOz).commit();

    EditText feedingHrInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feeding_hr_input);
    feedingHrs = feedingHrInput.getText().toString().trim();
    editor.putString("feeding_hr_input",feedingHrs).commit();

    // Submit nap information
    EditText awakeInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.awake_input);
    awakeHrs = awakeInput.getText().toString().trim();
    editor.putString("awake_input",awakeHrs).commit();


    // Submit notification active times

    // Return to main activity
    Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToMainActivity);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's the problem but you should never set absolute path strings, as you cannot know the root data path on all Android devices

Look at this : [Android basics data storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that wasn't good. I'm also getting the warning from Eclipse: "Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() 
 instead"

Any idea how I'd put that in my code? Would BABY_ONE-PROFILE.xml go in getPath()?

Answer (score 0):

The filenames for the SharedPreferences are internal, that's why there's an API. Try replacing

```
if (file2.exists())
```

with this

```
if(babyTwoProfile.contains("name"))
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed that part! Thank you! :)